# Ler várias url´s ao mesmo tempo gravando informações em Banco de Dados

Tags: php

Estou obtendo, a partir de algumas `url´s` fornecida por uma `api` da `Climatempo`, informações sobre previsão do tempo, nessas `url´s` 
devo informar as cidades que desejo consultar, ou seja, seus `id´s` e as mesmas me retornam um `xml` com as informações que preciso para gravar em meu banco de dados.
O problema que estou tendo é, como ler as informações de várias `url´s` ao mesmo tempo, fiz um teste criando uma estrutura para tentar resolver isso, mas estou com dificuldades para faze-lo funcionar.
Inicialmente fiz um loop para buscar os id´s das cidades no meu banco, se existe registros tento fazer um update e se não, tento o insert, dentro desse contexto
só consigo obter as informações da primeira `url`.

Vou postar o código completo, espero ter conseguido explicar de forma clara a minha dificuldade.

```
require_once('../Connections/con.php');

mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
$query_rcCidades = "SELECT * FROM PrevisaoCidade WHERE PrevisaoCidade.ativo = 1 ORDER BY PrevisaoCidade.IdCidade";
$rcCidades = mysql_query($query_rcCidades, $conCons) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rcCidades = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcCidades);
$totalRows_rcCidades = mysql_num_rows($rcCidades);


do {

    // CIDADES CADASTRADAS
    $cCidades = $row_rcCidades['IdCidade'];

    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/rain?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/temperature?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/wind?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/humidity?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/icon?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $url = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/uv?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';

    // PERMISSÃO 
    $post = array(  
        'key' => '',  
        'client' => '', 
        'nocache' => true,  
        'type' => 'xml',  
        'application' => 'Previsão 15 dias - Cidades'  
    );  

    // OBTENDO PERMISSÃO  
    $http = array(  
        'method' => 'POST',  
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
        'content' => http_build_query($post)  
    );  

    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $http));   
    $request = file_get_contents($url, true, $context); 
    $item =  simplexml_load_string($request);           

    // DATA PARA INSERÇÃO E/OU UPDATE
    $DataAux = substr((string)$item->data->item['dateBegin'], 0, -9);

    // SELECIONANDO TODAS AS OPÇÕES
    foreach($item->data->item->weather->item as $reg) {   

        // $data_aux  = substr($data,6,4).'-'.substr($data,3,2).'-'.substr($data,0,2);

        // ZERANDO O ARRAY
        $data = array();

            // CHUVA                
            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'precipitation' => (string)$reg['precipitation'],
                'probability' => (string)$reg['probability'],
                'date' => (string)$reg['date']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $Prec = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['precipitation'];
            $Prob = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['probability'];

            // TEMPERATURA  
            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'TMin' => (string)$reg['min'],
                'TMax' => (string)$reg['max']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $TMin = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['min'];
            $TMax = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['max'];

            // VENTO    
            $data['api']['data']['item']['locale']['id']        = (string)$item->data->item->locale['id'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['locale']['name']      = (string)$item->data->item->locale['name'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['locale']['latitude']  = (string)$item->data->item->locale['latitude'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['locale']['longitude'] = (string)$item->data->item->locale['longitude'];

            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'direction' => (string)$reg['direction'],                   
                'minVelocity' => (string)$reg['minVelocity'],               
                'maxVelocity' => (string)$reg['maxVelocity']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $VenDir = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['direction'];              
            $VelMin = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['minVelocity'];    
            $VelMax = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['maxVelocity'];

            // UMIDADE RELATIVA         
            $data['api']['data']['item']['dateBegin'] = (string)$item->data->item['dateBegin'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['dateEnd']   = (string)$item->data->item['dateEnd'];   
            $data['api']['data']['item']['latitude']  = (string)$item->data->item->locale['latitude'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['longitude'] = (string)$item->data->item->locale['longitude'];         

            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS                 
                'UmiMin' => (string)$reg['min'],
                'UmiMax' => (string)$reg['max']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS                      
            $UmMin = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['min'];
            $UmMax = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['max']; 

            // ÍCONES
            $data['api']['data']['item']['dateBegin'] = (string)$item->data->item['dateBegin'];
            $data['api']['data']['item']['dateEnd']   = (string)$item->data->item['dateEnd'];           

            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS                 
                'morning' => (string)$reg['morning'],   
                'afternoon' => (string)$reg['afternoon'],
                'night' => (string)$reg['night'],   
                'day' => (string)$reg['day'],
                'pt' => (string)$reg['pt']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS                      
            $IcoManha = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['morning'];
            $IcomTarde = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['afternoon'];   
            $IcoNoite = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['night'];
            $IcoDia = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['day'];
            $Frase = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['pt'];                  

            // UV               
            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'UvMax' => (string)$reg['max']                      

            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $UvMax = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['max'];         

        // INSERT DOS SERVIÇOS
        mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
        $sql = "SELECT Data, IdCidade FROM PrevisaoClima WHERE Data = '$DataAux' AND IdCidade = $cCidades";
        $rcDados = mysql_query($sql, $conCons) or die(mysql_error());
        $row_rcDados = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcDados);
        $totalRows_rcDados = mysql_num_rows($rcDados);

        if ($totalRows_rcDados > 0) {               
            mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
            $sql = "UPDATE `cpCons_webCons`.`PrevisaoClima` SET `Frase`='$Frase', `TempMin`='$TMin', `TempMax`='$TMax', `ProbChuva`='$Prob', `PrecisaoChuva`='$Prec', `IconeManha`='$IcoManha', `IconeTarde`='$IcoTarde', `IconeNoite`='$IcoNoite', `IconeDia`='$IcoDia', `VentoDir`='$VenDir', `VentoMax`='$VenMax', `VentoMin`='$VenMin', `Umidade`='$UmMax', `Uv`='$UvMax' WHERE `Data`='$DataAux' AND `IdCidade` = $cCidades";
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conCons);
            if (!$result) {
                $message  = 'ERRO: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                $message .= 'Query: ' . $sql;
                die($message);
            }
        } else {
            //Cria os dados da importação
            mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `cpCons_webCons`.`PrevisaoClima` (`Data`, `IdCidade`, `Frase`, `TempMin`, `TempMax`, `ProbChuva`, `PrecisaoChuva`, `IconeManha`, `IconeTarde`, `IconeNoite`, `IconeDia`, `VentoDir`, `VentoMax`, `VentoMin`, `Umidade`, `Uv`) VALUES ('$DataAux', '$cCidades', '$Frase', '$TMin', '$TMax', '$Prob', '$Prec', '$IcoManha', '$IcoTarde', '$IcoNoite', '$IcoDia', '$VenDir', '$VenMax', '$VenMin', '$UmiMax', '$UvMax')";
            $result = mysql_query($sql, $conCons);
            if (!$result) {
                $message  = 'ERRO: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                $message .= 'Query: ' . $sql;
                die($message);
            }
        }
    }           

} while ($row_rcCidades = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcCidades));
```

Comment: Por que a variavel $url tem seu conteudo sobre escrito varias vezes?

Comment: Não teria que armazenar as URL's em um array e depois realizar um laço de repetição nesse array para realizar a conexão para cada URL em especifico?

Comment: Ai é que está, a minha tentativa também foi isso, teria como postar uma dica de como ficaria?

Comment: veja se minha resposta te ajuda, abçs

Comment: Talvez o mais preocupante aí é se o webservice permitirá tantas conexões em curto tempo. Se não possui nenhum acordo que o permita, podem não gostar e bloquear o acesso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você tem que separar as URLs e os dados obtidos para cada requisição:

```
$urlChuva = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/rain?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
$urlTemp = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/temperature?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
$urlVento = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/wind?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
$urlHumi = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/humidity?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
$urlIcon = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/icon?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
$urlUV = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/uv?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
```

depois executar uma requisição para cada URL:

```
 $request = file_get_contents($urlChuva, true, $context); 
 $itemChuva =  simplexml_load_string($request);
 $request = file_get_contents($urlTemp, true, $context); 
 $itemTemp =  simplexml_load_string($request);
```

...

e processá-las separadamente, já que cada requisição vem com uma estrutura diferente.

Segue código apenas com Chuva e Temperatura, tem que implementar os outros

```
<?php 

require_once('../Connections/con.php');

mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
$query_rcCidades = "SELECT * FROM PrevisaoCidade WHERE PrevisaoCidade.ativo = 1 ORDER BY PrevisaoCidade.IdCidade";
$rcCidades = mysql_query($query_rcCidades, $conCons) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rcCidades = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcCidades);
$totalRows_rcCidades = mysql_num_rows($rcCidades);


do {

    // CIDADES CADASTRADAS
    $cCidades = $row_rcCidades['IdCidade'];

    $urlChuva = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/rain?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
    $urlTemp = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/temperature?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $urlVento = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/wind?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $urlHumi = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/humidity?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"'; 
    $urlIcon = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/icon?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';
    $urlUV = 'http://api.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/forecast/15days/uv?idlocale="'.$cCidades.'"';

    // PERMISSÃO 
    $post = array(  
        'key' => '',  
        'client' => '', 
        'nocache' => true,  
        'type' => 'xml',  
        'application' => 'Previsão 15 dias - Cidades'  
    );  

    // OBTENDO PERMISSÃO  
    $http = array(  
        'method' => 'POST',  
        'header' => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',  
        'content' => http_build_query($post)  
    );  

    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => $http));   
    $request = file_get_contents($urlChuva, true, $context); 
    $itemChuva =  simplexml_load_string($request);
    $request = file_get_contents($urlTemp, true, $context); 
    $itemTemp =  simplexml_load_string($request);       
    //OUTRAS REQUISIÇÕES...

    // DATA PARA INSERÇÃO E/OU UPDATE
    $DataAux = substr((string)$item->data->item['dateBegin'], 0, -9);

    // SELECIONANDO CHUVA
    $Prec = null;
    $Prob = null;
    foreach($itemChuva->data->item->weather->item as $reg) {   

        // $data_aux  = substr($data,6,4).'-'.substr($data,3,2).'-'.substr($data,0,2);

        // ZERANDO O ARRAY
        $data = array();

            // CHUVA                
            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'precipitation' => (string)$reg['precipitation'],
                'probability' => (string)$reg['probability'],
                'date' => (string)$reg['date']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $Prec = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['precipitation'];
            $Prob = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['probability'];
    }

    // SELECIONANDO TEMPERATURA
    $TMin = null;
    $TMax = null;
    foreach($itemTemp->data->item->weather->item as $reg) {   

        // $data_aux  = substr($data,6,4).'-'.substr($data,3,2).'-'.substr($data,0,2);

        // ZERANDO O ARRAY
        $data = array();

            // TEMPERATURA  
            $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][] = array 
            (
                // LENDO OS NÓS
                'TMin' => (string)$reg['min'],
                'TMax' => (string)$reg['max']
            );

            // ATRIBUINDO AS VARIÁVEIS      
            $TMin = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['min'];
            $TMax = $data['api']['data']['item']['weather']['item'][0]['max'];
    }


    //RESTANTE DOS PROCESSAMENTOS


    //OS COMANDOS DO BANCO FICAM FORA DO LOOP QUE PERCORRE O RETORNO DE DADOS
    // INSERT DOS SERVIÇOS
    mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
    $sql = "SELECT Data, IdCidade FROM PrevisaoClima WHERE Data = '$DataAux' AND IdCidade = $cCidades";
    $rcDados = mysql_query($sql, $conCons) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_rcDados = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcDados);
    $totalRows_rcDados = mysql_num_rows($rcDados);

    if ($totalRows_rcDados > 0) {               
        mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
        $sql = "UPDATE `cpCons_webCons`.`PrevisaoClima` SET `Frase`='$Frase', `TempMin`='$TMin', `TempMax`='$TMax', `ProbChuva`='$Prob', `PrecisaoChuva`='$Prec', `IconeManha`='$IcoManha', `IconeTarde`='$IcoTarde', `IconeNoite`='$IcoNoite', `IconeDia`='$IcoDia', `VentoDir`='$VenDir', `VentoMax`='$VenMax', `VentoMin`='$VenMin', `Umidade`='$UmMax', `Uv`='$UvMax' WHERE `Data`='$DataAux' AND `IdCidade` = $cCidades";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conCons);
        if (!$result) {
            $message  = 'ERRO: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Query: ' . $sql;
            die($message);
        }
    } else {
        //Cria os dados da importação
        mysql_select_db($database_conCons, $conCons);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `cpCons_webCons`.`PrevisaoClima` (`Data`, `IdCidade`, `Frase`, `TempMin`, `TempMax`, `ProbChuva`, `PrecisaoChuva`, `IconeManha`, `IconeTarde`, `IconeNoite`, `IconeDia`, `VentoDir`, `VentoMax`, `VentoMin`, `Umidade`, `Uv`) VALUES ('$DataAux', '$cCidades', '$Frase', '$TMin', '$TMax', '$Prob', '$Prec', '$IcoManha', '$IcoTarde', '$IcoNoite', '$IcoDia', '$VenDir', '$VenMax', '$VenMin', '$UmiMax', '$UvMax')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conCons);
        if (!$result) {
            $message  = 'ERRO: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
            $message .= 'Query: ' . $sql;
            die($message);
        }
    }   

} while ($row_rcCidades = mysql_fetch_assoc($rcCidades));
```

Comment: Para ficar "melhor", poderia trocar toda esse trecho do `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` por `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: Trabalho com o postgresql, acho que não tenho essa opção lá. Mas no Mysql do adventistapr, ele pode implementar vai melhorar bastante. Um detalhe que estava sendo executado os comandos do SGDB dentro do loop que percorria o retorno dos dados.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, agradeço pela dedicação e qualidade do código, estou verificando todas as dicas possíveis.
Daniel Omine, agradeço de igual modo a dica, valeu.